# How to keep splash screen befor network connet untill the network is ok by backgm and enter the youtube page

Tags: linux, networking, splash-screen, cobalt

1. At normal, when the network is not ok, launch cobalt, it will show the splash screen and pop a network error dialog, and exit the launch flow.
2. So how to keep splash screen(no network) and enter the youtube page(after the network is ok)? So it can keep splash screen about 15s and enter youtube page when the network is ok by backgm. In other words, keep splash screen until the network is ok, and enter youtube page.
3. So cobalt can retry to judge the network connection?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have options on your network error dialog like "troubleshoot network", "retry", "close" when the network issue happens. Users might select "retry" and if the network is recovered in the mean time, it will work.

Comment: In fact, the platform will launch Youtube when it turn on, the network module is not  ok, so we should wait at the splash screen untill the network is ok. It should no people operation. We can accept that the splash screen keep a long time.So uninclude user's select, how we can make it work ?

Comment: If you want to preload the YouTube app, I recommend you to make your platform to launch smart apps after the network connection is established. Otherwise, you will face with the same issue with other apps in the future when you have to preload other apps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you load Cobalt when the network is down and you want it to keep retrying to load YouTube forever, without user interaction. For that, immediately call `SbSystemPlatformErrorCallback` with `kSbSystemPlatformErrorResponsePositive` from your implementation of `SbSystemRaisePlatformError`.

Obviously, you only want to do it when Cobalt is running in background. Make sure that your implementation of `SbSystemRaisePlatformError` present an actual dialog box when Cobalt is interactive.

Comment: I think that keep retrying to load YouTube forever will consume much resource of the platform. There could be a case where the connection will never be established for some time being, but the process will continuously trying to reconnect in the background.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact, we don't need the preload, we only want to show the splash screen early. When the TV turn on, it will launch Youtube and Show the Splash screen firstly, and when the network is ok, Youtube can enter the page. We accept that when the network is not ok, cobalt can retry untill the network is ok, the splash screen show keep all the time untill the network is ok, so enter youtube page.

Comment: Trying to reach YouTube endlessly while Cobalt is interactive is not a great idea. What if user's network is truly down? Users must have an affordance to cancel YouTube loading. As Daniel suggested, initialize your platform network stack first, then launch Cobalt.